# PHP Instance create Issue

Tags: php, session

I'm using php static function to create instance for SESSION.

Issue is, while creating an instance of an object is created on every time when data is insertion.

So i cant add more than one data.

If its more than one, then the existing data is removed[New Object Created.]

MY CODE:

```
private static $session;

public static function startSession(array $config = array())
{
    if (self::$session == null) {
        self::$session = new lShopSession();
        self::$session = self::$session->getSession();
    }
    dd(self::$session);
    return self::$session;
}

function test()
{

    $lshop = self::startSession();
    $lshop->set('name', 'xxxx');
    $lshop = self::startSession();
    $lshop->set('name2', 'yyyy');

    dd(self::startSession());

}
```

MY OUTPUT:

```
[
  'name2' => 'yyyy'
]
```

But the first one is removed.

Any solution for this issue...?

Comment: I want only one instance to manage session.
If i add more than one item at the same time, then it keeps both, But if i add in one by one, then the existing one is removed and new object is created.

Comment: Maybe you want to create a class to manage sessions?

Comment: Yep, but here datas are destroyed on every new data insertion.

Comment: pos your $lshop->set() function code, and what output are you expecting? Post more code, so we could help. Or you are using magic methods?

Comment: instead of this (self::$session == null) , try `if(isset(self::$session));` OR define specifying null `private static $session=null`;

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not an answer, but I can't format this code properly in the comments, sry.

I don't actually know what happens in your `lShopSession` class and in `dd()` function, but here is simple example, that works (I tried to make this code more simplified and as much closer to original as I can) :

> of course it's not a production code, here is one-connection test, without actual session detection

```
<?php

class TestSession {
    public $data;

    // here is no code that restore session for user

    public function set($key, $val) {
        $this->data[$key] = $val;
    }
}

class TestManager {
    private static $session = null;

    public static function startSession() {
        if (is_null(self::$session)) {
            self::$session = new TestSession;
        }
       return self::$session;
    }

    public function test() {
        $l = self::startSession();
        $l->set('name', 'val');

        $l = self::startSession();
        $l->set('name2', 'val2');

        var_dump(self::startSession());
    }
}

$a = new TestManager;
$a->test();
```

results:

```
class Session#2 (1) {
  public $data =>
  array(2) {
    'name' =>
    string(3) "val"
    'name2' =>
    string(4) "val2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Here every time when new request is coming then the static variable "$session" is set to NULL.

So new object is created.

So new Datas only stored and old one is removed.

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan, I expected that your lShopSession class detects and restore actual session. There not enough code in your question, open / post your `lShopSession->getSession()` function source and class source that returned as result from `lShopSession->getSession()` or `lShopSession->set()` function source, probably here is an errors.